# Select rows from a table where id in another second table based on second table ids shows results top as well as next results as it is + Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have users table

users

```
id       name          
1        test1         
2        test2
3        test3
4        test4
5        test5
6        test6
7        test7
8        test8
9        test9
10       test10
```

Payment

```
id  userid  name
1     5     test5
2     3     test3
3     9     test9
```

i want results like this

```
id     name
3      test3
5      test5
9      test9
1      test1
2      test2
4      test4  
6      test6
7      test7
8      test8
10     test10
```

i want whoever pays the amount that one should be display in top order by.

Comment: Use join to get the desired result set. 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: ya off course, i wrote joins, total results doesn't displays.

Comment: @juergen d, plz guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce your desired results:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 1 AS RN  
FROM users a
INNER join payments b
ON a.id=b.userid

UNION ALL

SELECT a.id, a.name, 2 AS RN 
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN payments b
ON a.id=b.userid
WHERE b.id IS NULL
ORDER BY RN, a.id
```

The first query simply selects the `id` and `name` columns for rows that appear in the `payments` table.

The second query gets the `id` and `name` columns for rows that **do not** appear in the `payments` table.

The `UNION ALL` simply merges the results together.

Notice the `1 AS RN` and the `2 AS RN` that are in the queries. This is an extra column that I have added so that the results can be ordered how you wanted. You can simply ignore this when you process the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.`id` id, u.`name` NAME 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN payment p
ON u.id=p.userid

UNION

SELECT u.`id` id, u.`name` NAME 
FROM users u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with  `LEFT JOIN` and `ORDER BY`:

`SELECT 
    user.id, user.name
FROM
    user
        LEFT JOIN
    payment ON user.id = payment.userid
ORDER BY payment.id DESC, user.id`

This would fulfill your requirement, "i want whoever pays the amount that one should be display in top order by". But if you want the results as shown in the results you have given:

`SELECT 
    user.id, user.name
FROM
    user
        LEFT JOIN
    payment ON user.id = payment.userid
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN payment.id IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END , payment.id , user.id`